# packet_write_wait: Connection to 10.0.0.8 port 22: Broken pipe after sudo service elasticsearch start

Tags: ssh, elasticsearch

I'm getting the weirdest error. After running config management to install elasticsearch on an instance, when I do `sudo service elasticsearch start` I get a `Broken pipe` error and ssh cuts out. Then after less than a minute I can ssh into the machine again, but elasticsearch isn't running. I try it again and same thing.

There's nothing in the elasticsearch logs, and I'm just at a loss of what to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be an issue with a new kernel that has been deployed on GCP for the Ubuntu 16.04 LTS OS.

Problem Kernel: 

`uname -a
Linux elasticsearch-1-vm 4.13.0-1007-gcp #10-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jan 12 13:56:47 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Proper Kernel: 

`uname -a
Linux elasticsearch-1-vm 4.13.0-1006-gcp #9-Ubuntu SMP Mon Jan 8 21:13:15 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

To fix the issue with the GCP instances, I ran: 

`sudo apt remove 4.13.0-1007-gcp
sudo apt install 4.13.0-1006-gcp
exit`

Then in google cloud console, restart the instance, then SSH back in then: 

`sudo service elasticsearch start`